# Bitbucket - How to enforce that merges are done first to Develop branch and then to Master branch?

Tags: bitbucket, githooks, git-flow, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-pipelines

Gitflow workflow states that Hotfix branches will be merged to both Develop and Master branches.
Since engineers forgot more than once to merge their hotfix to Develop, I want to mandate that the merge to develop is done first.
How can I configure Bitbucket to block merges of commits, that do not already exist in Develop, to master?

Comment: Your tags are a bit confusing here - is this for Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (self-hosted)?

Comment: @JimRedmond, It's Bitbucket Server (self-hosted).

Comment: Got it. You should remove the "bitbucket-pipelines" tag, then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about BitBucket, but if you're able to install your own hooks, it's easy enough to script whatever you want in a pre-recive or update hook.

The following is an (untested) example, there are perhaps more efficient git commands to accomplish this, I'm not sure.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ... << Code to set up your hook variables here >>> ...

if [ "$(git branch Develop --contains $new_rev | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: You must commit to Develop first and then merge"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: You can indeed install your own server-side hooks in Bitbucket Server. It's not encouraged, since it's somewhat opaque (easy to install hooks, forget about them, then have users or future admins going down a troubleshooting rabbit hole for days or weeks). Read [How to create a simple hook in Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-create-a-simple-hook-in-bitbucket-server-779171711.html) (skip past the stuff about Java hooks, it describes basic script hooks further down).